# polylogarithm integrating by parts and expanding

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, polylogarithm, quantum-field-theory

[image: polylog]

Question: how to go from equation (3) to equation (4)?

This is from Horatio Nastase "Intro to Quantum Field Theory" book (Cambridge University Press, 2019) , chapter 59. The reader is supposed to massage equation (3) into equation (4) with the help of the given polylogarithm formulas (1) and (2). I suppose I must integrate by parts twice. That gives a k(k-1) term, which equals k!/(k-2)!. Also, for k=0 the surface term from the first integration gives -z/(z-1), which substracted from 1/(1-z) gives the 1 in (4). But what about the 1/t term? And what about the z? I need the 1/t in (4) and only z in log(1-zt) in (4). Do I have to use equation (2) somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's drop the limits for a bit ... we shall put them in at the end.

Integrate by parts 
\begin{eqnarray*}
\int \frac{z}{(1-zt)^2} ( \ln(t))^k  dt = \frac{( \ln(t))^k}{(1-zt)} -k \int \frac{ (\ln(t))^{k-1}}{t(1-zt)} dt.
\end{eqnarray*}
Partial fractions
\begin{eqnarray*}
 \frac{ 1}{t(1-zt)} = \frac{1}{t} +\frac{z}{1-zt}.
\end{eqnarray*}
So we have two integrals to consider
\begin{eqnarray*}
\int \frac{ ( \ln(t))^{k-1}}{t}   dt = \frac{( \ln(t))^k}{k}.
\end{eqnarray*}
And the other integral
\begin{eqnarray*}
\int  ( \ln(t))^{k-1} \frac{z }{1-tz}   dt = ( \ln(t))^{k-1}  \ln(1-zt)- (k-1) \int ( \ln(t))^{k-2}  \ln(1-zt) dt.
\end{eqnarray*}
Putting these together & including the limits, gives
\begin{eqnarray*}
\int_{0}^{1} \frac{z}{(1-zt)^2} ( \ln(t))^k  dt = \left[ \frac{( \ln(t))^k}{(1-zt)} -( \ln(t))^k-k ( \ln(t))^{k-1}  \ln(1-zt)  \right]_0^1 \\ +k(k-1) \int ( \ln(t))^{k-2}  \ln(1-zt) dt.
\end{eqnarray*}
There is some subtle cancellations with the lower limit, but the whole square bracket evaluates to zero & we are done.

Comment: Great. Thanks a lot!